# What are the combinations for the mutates berries?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

These are the mutations I've already heard of:

- Aspear + Leppa = Hondew
- Chesto + Persim = Kelpsy
- Iapapa + Mago = Pomeg
- Oran + Pecha = Qualot
- Sitrus + Lum = Tamato
- Hondew + Yache = Petaya
- Kelpsy + Wacan = Apicot

I wanted to know if there were any others that I don't already have.
Help?

Plus... I've gotten these by accident. Do I put one plant on Surprise Mulch and the other on another type or do they both need to be on the Surprise Mulch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the list of the Berries you can get from [Mutations](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Berry_fields#Mutation):

[image]

Regarding the **Mutation** process:

> Mutation will sometimes occur when two different types of Berries are grown next to each other. Once a certain mutation has been performed once, the formula for it can be reviewed with the Scientist in the Berry grower's hut. Using **Surprise Mulch** or **Amaze Mulch** on the trees involved increases the chance of a mutation.